# Best way how to track iframe separately from the site on the same domain

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

On my site I have feature for users, that they can embed video on their page with iframe. Now I'm tracking classic page view and iframe view same way. So my analytics stats are not correct. I wanna separate this tracking to know how much of visitors I have on page and how much of them on iframe. I'm using google analytics.

I'm looking forward what do you suggest.

BTW: I am using special url for embeded video but still on the same domain.

Comment: can you paste your current tracking code here? That impacts significantly the way you ought to go about the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've got a special URL for the embedded video, you could use filters to include or exclude that URL for a Google Analytics profile, and keep the same analytics code on every page.

I'd recommend:

1. Keeping one profile unfiltered, showing all traffic
2. One profile that filters out the iframe URL
3. One profile that only shows the iframe URL

More info about  [Google Analytics accounts & profiles](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts?hl=en#profiles)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a simple GET-Parameter in your URLs? For example: `http://www.website.com/video.flv?type=embedded` 
or

```
http://www.website.com/video.flv?type=extern
```

Unfortunately I don't know exactly, how  Google Analytics handles same URLs with various GET-Parameter.

Other way is using a simple redirect script or htaccess rule.